# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using instantiateViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to make a Home Screen Quick action to open a specific view controller, when I run the app I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0xdac11530)` error on the line shown below. Any ideas as to solve this?

```swift
func navigateToMoreDoggosVC() {
        
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let moreDoggosVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "moreDoggosViewController") //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=261, address=0x********)
        let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        
        navVC?.pushViewController(moreDoggosVC, animated: true)
        
    }
```

if you need any more info i would be happy to edit the question.

Comment: you want to set moreDoggosVC as InitialViewController or want to move from home screen to moreDoggosVC(home screen will be your intial View Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push a view controller on launching the app.
You need to set a `rootViewController` and then make it `makeKeyAndVisible`.

How can we achieve this see below code:

```
func navigateToMoreDoggosVC() {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let moreDoggosVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "moreDoggosViewController")
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: moreDoggosVC)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

You need to add this code in the `SceneDelegate.swift` file and call it from the `willConnectTo` function.

[image]